# Android network interface configuration

Tags: android, networking, rndis

I'm developing the RNDIS host functionality on Android-based devices. I've already compiled and installed appropriate Android drivers but have faced with another problem: how to set IP address of the network interface (usb0) in Android automatically? I can set IP for the interface manually like `ifconfig, ip addr` etc., but I need to implement these operations automatically after the network interfaces up automatically. I know how it is done in Linux operating systems (editing files like /etc/network/interfaces) but I didn't find any information about Android OS.

Comment: What's the transport type of the interface? This for more context:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#hasTransport(int)

Also, what version of Android are you using?